# Is my SD card beyond repair?

Tags: disk-format, sd-card

I've looked on other questions and from those answers I have tried SDFormatter and it produced this error:

```
[ERROR] Invalid end of sector signature: 0x4536
[ERROR] exfat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Initializing cached values failed: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Generated invalid volume. exfat_volume_create returned: 22 (Invalid argument)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe someone can help you but I'm thinking this question is off topic for this site because it's not Apple related.

Comment: Are you using the macOS-compatible SD Memory Card Formatter from sdcard.org?

Comment: You do not want to trust you data to a flacky card.  What happens when you try formatting with disk utility.